# Ключи JSONObject выводятся случайным образом

Tags: android, java, json

И снова здравствуйте!
Опять загадки преподносит Java по неопытности...

Есть JSON:

```
{
    "data": {
        "task_1": {
            "name": "task_1"
        },
        "task_2": {
            "name": "task_2"
        },
        "task_3": {
            "name": "task_3"
        },
        "task_4": {
            "name": "task_4"
        }
    }
}
```

Есть код, который обрабатывает этот JSON  выводит ключи объектов на экран:

```
 String jsonStr = "{\"data\":{\"task_1\":{\"name\":\"task_1\"},\"task_2\":{\"name\":\"task_2\"},\"task_3\":{\"name\": \"task_3\"},\"task_4\":{\"name\": \"task_4\"}}}";
 try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
    JSONObject data = jsonObject.getJSONObject("data");
    Iterator<?> i = data.keys();
    while (i.hasNext()){
       String objName = i.next().toString();
       Log.d(TAG + ":JSON_TEST:", objName);
    }
 } catch (JSONException e) {
    Log.d(TAG + ":JSON_TEST:", e.getMessage());
 }
```

Вопрос: почему при выводе ключи перемешались и вывелись не так, как они стоят в JSON?

[image]

P.S.: к сожалению, код на ideone.com запустить не смог, там не поддерживается

```
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Comment: Указывайте пожалуйста в названии вопроса информацию, которая поможет по названию понять, о чем пойдет речь в вопросе.    
"Java знать хочу! =)" ни коим образом не говорит о том, что вопрос о парсинге JSON.    
Точно так же, как и ваш предыдущий "И снова Java!"

Comment: @metalurgus - Понял. Исправил.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Потому что:

> A JSONObject is an **unordered** collection of name/value pairs

Ищите ответы на подобные вопросы в документации. В частности для [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/javadoc/org/json/JSONObject.html).

Comment: @a_gura - Спасибо!

Answer (score 5):

Упорядоченными являются элементы массива. То есть у вас data является объектом, и task_X - его поля. Порядок полей не важен.  
А вот если бы они передавались, как массив...

```
{
    "data": [
        {
            "name": "task_1"
        },
        {
            "name": "task_2"
        },
        {
            "name": "task_3"
        },
        {
            "name": "task_4"
        }
    ]
}
```

то оставались бы упорядоченными

Comment: @metalurgus - Спасибо!